# iOS: url-scheme fb://event/%llu no longer working in 6.1.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

opening the Facebook app with the URL scheme

```
fb://event/%llu
```

used to work up until update 6.1.1. Now the event view opens empty and nothing is displayed. Has the URL scheme changed or am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook seems to have changed to use fb://profile/ for everything. Change event to profile and it should work.

```
fb://profile/%llu
```

This is the downside of using any URL scheme, they are undocumented and the app creator, in this case Facebook, can change or remove them completely at will.

Comment: @skladek so you know how to share a link of a random page with the Facebook Url Schemes?